# Discord py - ERROR: Unable to extract JS player URL

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Hey guys,**

I am trying to make my own discord music bot with youtube-dl.

Since the original youtube-dl isnt available anymore I use a copy of the latest version

> https://github.com/l1ving/youtube-dl

Sometimes the bot works fine but sometimes I get this error

> ERROR: Unable to extract JS player URL

The funny thing is that this does not happen everytime - 6/10 cases

**What does my code look like:**

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import os
import youtube_dl

import urllib.parse, urllib.request, re
import requests

from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed, FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.utils import get

'''

INSTALLING YOUTUBE-DL

pip install -U git+https://github.com/l1ving/youtube-dl

'''

queue = []

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0'
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False, play=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream or play))

        if 'entries' in data:
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):

        if not ctx.message.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel!")
            return
        else:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            await ctx.send(f'Connected to ``{channel}``')

        await channel.connect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):

        try:

            async with ctx.typing():
                player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
                ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

            await ctx.send(f':mag_right: **Searching for** ``' + url + '``\n<:youtube:763374159567781890> **Now Playing:** ``{}'.format(player.title) + "``")

        except:

            await ctx.send("Somenthing went wrong - please try again!")

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        voice.pause()

        user = ctx.message.author.mention
        await ctx.send(f"Bot was paused by {user}")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        voice.resume()

        user = ctx.message.author.mention
        await ctx.send(f"Bot was resumed by {user}")

    @commands.command()
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
        user = ctx.message.author.mention
        await voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send(f'Disconnected from {user}')


    @play.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Music(client))
```

I have no clue why this just happens sometimes?? Maybe one of you guys know the answer :)

Comment: https://github.com/blackjack4494/yt-dlc/issues/13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Repository unavailable due to DMCA takedown.

This repository is currently disabled due to a **DMCA takedown notice**. We have disabled public access to the repository. The notice has been publicly posted.

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/26168